# How could the following code be adjusted to prevent a buffer overflow?

Tags: c, buffer-overflow

```
void updateConfigParams( void ) {
    char buffer [512];
    int i = 0;

while (( c = readFromWireless ()) != NULL) 
{
    buffer [ i ] = c;
    i += 1; 
} 
writeConfigParams ( buffer );
}
```

I'm only getting to grips with buffer overflow so please could somebody show me how the following code needs to be changed to prevent a buffer overflow and also explain how the new code stops the writing past the end of the buffer.

Comment: Do you understand buffer overflow? If yes then its fairly trivial.

Comment: @bashrc That's the issue i'm struggling to understand it.

Comment: Wouldn't you just make sure it doesn't go over your 512 size??

Comment: What happens when i > 512?  There's nothing that prevents you running right off the end of the buffer.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I understand that the buffer size is 512 bytes but i don't know what code needs to be added/changed to prevent it going over 512.

Comment: If you don't understand that then you don't understand the most basic elements of the C language. If you're going to program in C, you might want to learn some first instead of asking people on the internet to solve trivial problems for you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
void updateConfigParams( void ) {
    char buffer [512];
    int i = 0;

    while (i < 512 && ( c = readFromWireless ()) != NULL) {
        buffer [ i++ ] = c;
    } 
    writeConfigParams ( buffer );
}
```

Comment: How does `writeConfigParams ( )` know how much of `buffer` to write?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add buffer size check at start of while loop
if(i == sizeof(buffer))
 break;

and add \0 at the end of buffer if writeConfigParams expects a string

Answer (score 0):

You Could add the following if Statement to check the Buffer Overflow condition. after incrementing  the variable i

```
i+=1;
if(i > 512)
    break;
```

Once the i reaches the buffer limit you will exit the loop.

Answer (score 0):

[Buffer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow) is when you try to write beyond the memory address allocated for the buffer.

In your case you have allocated `512` bytes, so your code should make sure that you never de-reference beyond `buffer + 511`. In other words

`buffer [i] // i should never exceed 511`

Your code should have if checks to stop taking input once your index counter reaches equal to the size of buffer.

Comment: The OP's question was how to do that so you didn't answer the question.

Comment: @CareyGregory 
"Your code should have if checks to stop taking input once your index counter reaches equal to the size of buffer."
Also see the OP's reply on my comment.
>>Do you understand buffer overflow?
>>@bashrc That's the issue i'm struggling to understand it.

Answer (score -1):

I would do something along the following lines:

```
bool
updateConfigParams( void ) {
  char buffer[512] = {};
  int i = 0;

  while( (c = readFromWireless()) != NULL ) {
    if( i == sizeof(buffer) - 1 ) {
      warn("readFromWireless exceeded %zu byte limit", sizeof(buffer));
      return false;
    } 
    buffer[i++] = c;
  }
  writeConfigParams( buffer );
  return true;
}
```

Depending on the state of your program, it might be more appropriate simply to call **err(3)**.  Important points are:

- When writing to an array, always ensure you're in bounds.
- When collecting input into an array, always be prepared for input that exceeds the array's size.  What to do with input you can't accept is application-dependent.
- When internal storage is exceeded by an action the programmer can't prevent at compile time -- such as a wireless device sending "too much" data -- inform the user *and* the program.  Above, the program emits a message, and the function returns an error status.
- Partial input is usually suspect and should not be accepted.

Edit: pursuant to a comment, I added initialization to `buffer`.  Since `writeConfigParams` takes no length parameter, perhaps it accepts a NUL-terminated string.

Comment: How does `writeConfigParams ( )` know how much of `buffer` to write?

Comment: And what is `c`? You're just relying on it defaulting to `int`?

Comment: @CareyGregory, I don't know what `c` is.  It certainly doesn't "default" to anything.    I don't have a declaration for `writeConfigParams`, either, and so on.  It's his code, and it doesn't compile.  He didn't ask to make it compile; he asked how to deal with buffer overflows.  That's the question I answered.  If my answer is going to be downvoted, I'd sure like to know how it fails to answer the question asked.

Comment: `c` will default to `int` in K&R C, which is why I asked. I don't know who downvoted so don't assume commenters did.

Comment: Re downvote, thanks, acknowledged.  Re K&R, not in this case.  You might be thinking of implicit return types for functions.  If a stray variable name shows up without being defined, that was an error, even on a PDP/8.  :-)

Comment: Eh, you're right. For some reason I was thinking k&C defaulted variables to int.